# Facebook Open Graph not working properly; no link previews

Tags: facebook-opengraph

i'm having some trouble with my OG tags. It is displaying properly in `<head>`, however Facebook Open Graph returned with a Bad Response Code.

Here is the URL: https://www.sentosa.com.sg/en/get-inspired/sentosa-guides/mums-recommend-fun-activities-on-sentosa/

[image]

```html
<head>
   <title data-react-helmet="true">Mums Recommend: Fun Family Activities On Sentosa</title>
   <meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:title" content="Mums Recommend: Fun Family Activities On Sentosa"/>
   <meta data-react-helmet="true" name="keywords" content="things to do, fun activities in sentosa, family"/>
   <meta data-react-helmet="true" name="title" content="Mums Recommend: Fun Family Activities On Sentosa"/>
   <meta data-react-helmet="true" name="description" content="It’s true – mothers know best!"/>
   <meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:description" content="It’s true – mothers know best!"/>
   <meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:url" content="https://www.sentosa.com.sg/get-inspired/sentosa-guides/mums-recommend-fun-activities-on-sentosa"/>
   <meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:image" content="https://www.sentosa.com.sg/-/media/sentosa/article-listing/articles/2021/mums-recommended-fun-activities-to-do-in-sentosa/mums_hero.jpg?revision=7e8e6d47-8f17-4686-8cf2-b34dc387a461"/>
   <link data-react-helmet="true" rel="canonical" href="https://www.sentosa.com.sg/get-inspired/sentosa-guides/mums-recommend-fun-activities-on-sentosa/"/>
   <link data-react-helmet="true" rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.sentosa.com.sg/-/media/sentosa/features/header/favicon-new.png?revision=b492cc89-69c8-448d-a928-15c3e56b2e88"/>
   <script data-react-helmet="true" async="true" src="https://assets.wogaa.sg/scripts/wogaa.js"></script>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"/>
   <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
   <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=DC-8858992"></script><script>function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)}window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[],gtag("config","DC-8858992")</script>
   <link href="/dist/sentosa/static/css/main.24239852.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
   <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-536FZZK" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
   <div id="root">
   <style data-styled="bhTETV gthcLv jWNKzs ffTmSH gzHAtR gXecBG bzgUGP cOeqpc kdJMol eUYsaW kHNbps ftjTQW stNPD cTYkaX eXgrYR kvnZyw dUFPwu dfcRpc kZrfbx cNdvkR fXtlEt PaNCb" data-styled-version="4.4.1">
```

Comment: Your server is responding to Facebook with a 503 Service Unavailable response (it may be responding to Twitter the same as I couldn’t get a card to validate). I accessed your URL using [Rex Swain viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) with Facebook’s user agent `facebookexternalhit/1.1` and Twitter’s `Twitterbot/1.0` - both worked. The message app KakaoTalk was able to access your OG info and send a rich link preview. You could check with your host as it seems to be an issue of your host blocking certain bots. *One unrelated note - your head tag should be right after the html tag.*

Comment: Thanks Rich. Will get our devs to look into this. This issue only happened when we implemented Azure Front Door to our whole site. Not sure if this could be a cause of this problem,

Answer (score 2):

I had the [same problem with Azure Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/273558/azure-front-door-returns-a-503-service-unavailable.html) - the issue appears to be caused by the combination of `Accept-Encoding` and `Range` headers - this causes Front Door to return a 503 response even though the backend server is capable of serving the response.

My solution was to create a Rules Engine rule that removed the `Accept-Encoding` header if there is also a `Range` header. This ensures that the crawling sites still get the correct 200 or 206 response with a payload that doesn't exceed their stated requirements.

The following rule worked for us for the social sharing tools that we tested (mainly Facebook, WhatsApp, Twitter, LinkedIn):

[image: Rules Engine Rule Configuration]

```
IF
  Condition: "Request header"
  Header name: "Range"
  Operator: "Any"
AND IF
  Condition: "Request header"
  Header name: "Accept-Encoding"
  Operator: "Contains"
  Header value: "gzip"
  Transform: "To lowercase"

THEN
  Action: "Request header"
  Operator: "Delete"
  Header name: "Accept-Encoding"
```

***Edit to add***

This recently stopped working for us, and it turned out to be because our server was returning inconsistent cache headers.

When the `cache-control` headers are internally consistent, everything is fine, for example:

Cacheable pages: `Cache-Control: public, max-age=1322`
or
Non-cacheable pages: `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache`

However some pages were returning:

`Cache-Control: public, no-store, max-age=1800`

Which appeared to be working "as expected" for normal requests (i.e. Front Door wasn't caching the pages) however when requested with a `Range` header (with or without an `Accept-Encoding` header), we started seeing the 503 error again. Correcting the cache-control header resolved the 503 with the `range` header.

Comment: – I saw your question to Microsoft and Sai Kishor’s explanation for why it was happening (when a request includes a range header, Front Door reaches out to the origin two or more times to confirm the request – if the request isn’t confirmed, Front Door responds with a 503). Were you able to create one rule that acts on all requests that include a range header, or did you have to create separate rules for Facebook and LinkedIn (and WhatsApp and any other application that wants to create a rich link preview)?

Comment: @RichDeBourke Updated with the single rule we're using - By basing it around the problem headers, it doesn't need to care about the user agent, which means that if new user agents start behaving in the same way they will still be served correct requests. Just because a user-agent accepts gzip encoding doesn't mean that you have to honour it.

Comment: Feel like I'm going around in circles here - this rule has recently stopped working for us - requesting cached pages with the Range header results in a 503 error from Front Door, but I can't remove the range header from the request.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I am facing the same issues. Any solutions to share?

Comment: @DANLEE - the repeated issue was solved when we stopped issuing conflicting cache-control headers.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Thanks. Do you think that if my Response Header for cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate and Request Header for cache-control:  no-cache would cause a problem?

Comment: @DANLEE - no, that response header should be fine. Just checking: Are you using Front Door in "Cache Enabled" mode, and have you already removed the `Accept-Encoding` request header? Are you able to remove one or more of the values in the cache-control response header from the server and try (that's how I confirmed the issue initially).

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid That's right, I am using Front Door, I've disabled the cache to eliminate any potential issues as for now. But I've removed Accept-Encoding and gzip as suggested by you and one of the Microsoft troubleshooting articles.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid In my case, I have FrontDoor setup in front of multiple backend Web App. I've noticed there's a number of random 503 errors each day. The requests themselves are valid, and retrying generally works, however, the initial request that fails is not hitting the backend Web App. The backend health at the times of the errors are also 100%, and it can't be a timeout because the error is immediate (timeout is also extended to 240 seconds). It seems like FrontDoor itself is having some kind of health issue, but there's no health issues mentioned. Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: @DANLEE - yep those were my symptoms as well, however if I issued the request **with the same headers** I would consistently get an immediate 503 error. Removing either the Range or Accepts headers solved the problem. The Front Door rules engine doesn't allow for removal of the Range header, but did allow for the Accepts header to be removed, which is the route I'd taken.